# Do we need to run pod install with Expo project

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm new with app developing. I'm using react-native 0.63.2 and i've created my project with Expo.
There are no ios and android folders
So, should we have to have these folders to run pod install and correctly link the React Native app to the futur iOS app or this is not necessary anymore?
Because with the command npx create-react-native-app to create a project, they do exist.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you don't need pod install here.. you can build your application without using xcode or android studio... expo handles it all :)

PS: for start use `expo start` and to build `expo build:ios`

Comment: Big thanks ! I've been searching how to add these folders to properly run pod install but i didn't found how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to install Pod. Just run expo start or expo build:ios